# Jmeter Favicon how to exclude?

Tags: jmeter

I did record with blazemeter a test.
Now it is giving me this error  The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. at the favicons.
Is there a way to exlude it from the jmeter script?

Or what is another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If the favicon is a separate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler - add a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to it, tick `Ignore status` box and set the expected response code to the actual one
- If the favicon comes with the ["embedded resources"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/)  you could add the next line to [user.properties file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter):

  ```
   httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
  ```

  and after JMeter restart the problem should go away

Comment: Thank you Dmitri.   it is not a seperate HTTP Request.      Stupid question but where can I find the user. properties file?

Comment: In "bin" folder of your JMeter installation

Comment: Tried it butgetting an error
Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Load time:292
Connect Time:98
Latency:292
Size in bytes:2092
Sent bytes:545
Headers size in bytes:1989
Body size in bytes:103
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:404
Response message:Not Found
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html
DataEncoding: null

I think now that it has to do with the cookie. 
Because when I click on the red things and set cookie then it is in read.
Is there a way to avoid that?
Sorry I am quite new with it.

Comment: It has been solved now. Thank you Dmitri.  The Response Assertion did his work :)